# Playing Video streams from a Service on a GSP page

Tags: java, sockets, grails, groovy, gsp

**Original Question**

I hit a wall, and I am hoping that someone here will be able to help me. I just started programming Grails a few weeks ago and this is my first project so please, if I may ask for all responses to be with examples, I would greatly appreciate it.

I am trying to develop a webpage that connects to one of my company's proprietary camera engines (written in c++). This "SocketSerivce" after you select a camera, should establish a TCP connection to the engine and request the stream (mjpeg/h264/etc).

My problem is, I have been able to successfully establish a socket Connection to the engine and request the stream, but I have no idea how to handle it, and everything I have tried has failed. What I would like is to have the video stream (mjpeg/h264/etc) play in a `<div id="VideoStreamContainer"></div>` on my GSP page.

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

**SocketService.groovy:**

```
def static getCameraStream(def ip, def port, def cam){
    final Socket sock = new Socket(ip, port)
    OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream()
    dataips = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    //s.setSoTimeout(3000)
    nThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            os << "Get /specialCommandtoRequestCameraStream"
            os.flush()
            while((readed = dataips.readLine()) != null){
                println("read:  " + readed)
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

If I have not provided you with enough information to my problem, I would be happy to answer any additional questions anyone has. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Update 1**

From the documentation I am reading over now, I realized something important I left out of my original question. The reason I would like to stream the video in a div tag (or some other html type tag) is because I would like to avoid using a "Flash" player. This webpage I am working on, I would like to be fully functional on all java enabled devices. But most of these same devices do not support/run Flash. This is why I am looking for non-Flash player solutions. I am sorry for not including this sooner.

**Update 2 8/1/2013 9:38PM @aduchate**

Could you(or anyone) possibly better explain how using this code I could tie it in with the GSP page? For instance, with this can I now have an html `<video>` tag receive the video stream from the controller? Or does the controller have the ability to render the video on the webpage without using a `<video>` tag?

If I didn't detail this well enough before, what I am trying to do is get a video stream (mjpeg/h264/etc) from a C++ engine that can be displayed on any webpage. "Video Engine" -> "Grails" -> "Html (GSP) webpage". I am using grails to establish & maintain the socket connection and the video streams I receive over the sockets I am trying to push/display on the GSP pages. That is the ultimate goal of the project.

**Update 3 8/2/2013 8:50AM**

Just wanted to say that I solved my error problem from last night. My issue still remains getting the video stream from the socket to display on the GSP page.

Comment: Can't you just connect a client-side player component directly to the camera engines? Or is it a requirement to stream everything through grails?

Comment: It is a requirement that it is streamed through grails. For now I am trying to just get the videos streaming for a proof of concept that I need to create. Later on, additional work/manipulation will be done to those camera streams.

Comment: Have you had a play with the [Grails GVPS plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/gvps)? [Source](https://github.com/rvanderwerf/grails-video), [Docs](https://github.com/rvanderwerf/grails-video/blob/master/doc/streaming-grails-slides-v2.pdf?raw=true).  It seems to do a lot more than you need, but the code for streaming the video might be in there somewhere?

Comment: No I have not. I haven't really figured out the whole plugin thing yet. I have just been focusing on getting small things working here and there. I will look at this now thank you. I just add this plugin through my IntelliJ IDE right?

Comment: I'd have a look through the source, then create a new project for experimentation and add (assuming grails 2.+) `compile ":gvps:0.3"` to the plugins section of BuildConfig.  I don't use an IDE, so I've no idea about adding plugins in IntelliJ, sorry :-(

Comment: The [magic seems to happen here](https://github.com/rvanderwerf/grails-video/blob/master/grails-app/services/com/cantina/lab/VideoService.groovy#L569) however, I have no idea if it is useful to you or indeed will work in your situation :-( Hopefully someone with streaming experience can jump in with an answer ;-)

Comment: Yes I am using grails 2.+. Thank you for providing me a direction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you simply wish to relay the stream you read from the socket as the content of the http response, you have to write the following code inside a **controller**:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def getCameraStream() {
  Socket sock = new Socket(params.ip, params.port as Integer)
  sock.withStreams { input, output ->
    output << "Get /specialCommandtoRequestCameraStream"
    output.flush()
    response.setContentType('video/mp4')
    IOUtils.copy(input,response.outputStream)
  }
  sock.close()
}
```

This code is not tested but should point you in the right direction.

Have fun with Grails